# How do i select all radio buttons in angular 6

Tags: typescript, angular6

I have a radio button in the table as action and when i click on that radio button all the radio buttons present in the each row should be selected and when i deselect the radio button they should be deselected.
I need some suggestions to implementation this in angular 2 or above versions.

Thanks in advance.
Abhishek

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe changes to your main radio button and when value changes you can set value of that radio button to others.

Sharing some sample code which can help you :

Say you have two radio button - radio1 and radio2 as FormControl.

```
        this.form = new FormGroup({
            'radio1': new FormControl(),
            'radio2': new FormControl()
        });
```

You have to check radio2 when radio1 is checked and uncheched when radio1 is unchecked.

```
    ngOnInit() {  
       this.form.get('radio1').valueChanges.subscribe( x => this.form.get('radio2').setValue(x));
    }
```